# PHP uses a network port to connect to the Redis service. RedisException: No such file or directory

Tags: php, redis

PHP uses a network port to connect to the Redis service. RedisException: No such file or directory.
I opened another redis but there was no problem.

```
[root@iZwz96u12ozbs8aqnrwvo9Z Lib]# ps aux | grep redis
root     18378  0.1  0.8 163100 16204 ?        Ssl  10:06   0:04 redis-5.0.5/src/redis-server 127.0.0.1:63306
root     22998  0.0  0.2 142952  5320 ?        Ssl  11:16   0:00 redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379
root     23130  0.0  0.0 112704   976 pts/0    R+   11:18   0:00 grep --color=auto redis
[root@iZwz96u12ozbs8aqnrwvo9Z Lib]# redis-cli -p 63306
127.0.0.1:63306> ping
PONG
127.0.0.1:63306> exit
[root@iZwz96u12ozbs8aqnrwvo9Z Lib]# redis-cli -p 6379
127.0.0.1:6379> ping
PONG
127.0.0.1:6379> exit
[root@iZwz96u12ozbs8aqnrwvo9Z Lib]# redis-server --version
Redis server v=3.2.12 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-3.6.0 bits=64 build=7897e7d0e13773f
[root@iZwz96u12ozbs8aqnrwvo9Z Lib]# ../../redis/redis-5.0.5/src/redis-server --version
Redis server v=5.0.5 sha=c956f3fe:0 malloc=jemalloc-5.1.0 bits=64 build=d7a4b6366565957e
```

Redis at 6379 works with my code, and the other doesn't work.

```php
// is bad
try {
    $this->redis = new Redis();
    $this->redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 63306);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    throw new Exception("Redis 连接失败_$e");
}
```

```php
// is work
try {
    $this->redis = new Redis();
    $this->redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    throw new Exception("Redis 连接失败_$e");
}
```

the correct output is:

```
{"code":0,"status":"成功","data":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
```

the error output is：

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: Redis 连接失败_RedisException: No such file or directory in /usr/share/nginx/html/exbook/app/Lib/WeChat.php:23
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/share/nginx/html/exbook/app/Lib/WeChat.php(23): Redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 63306)
#1 /usr/share/nginx/html/exbook/app/Lib/WeChat.php(52): App\Lib\WeChat->__construct()
#2 /usr/share/nginx/html/exbook/app/Lib/WeChat.php(135): App\Lib\WeChat::getWeChat()
#3 {main} in /usr/share/nginx/html/exbook/app/Lib/WeChat.php:25
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/share/nginx/html/exbook/app/Lib/WeChat.php(52): App\Lib\WeChat->__construct()
#1 /usr/share/nginx/html/exbook/app/Lib/WeChat.php(135): App\Lib\WeChat::getWeChat()
#2 {main}
  thrown in /usr/share/nginx/html/exbook/app/Lib/WeChat.php on line 25
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the port number.

On my centos, the redis port is less than 20000 and can work with php. It will report an error at a port number of 20000-30000. But any port that can be used, such as 63306, works with php on my manjaro.